# Weird Cauchy Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Can somebody help me in solving this weird Cauchy problem? I really don't know how to face it.

$$ 
\begin{cases}
y' = -\dfrac{(2x+y)\cos(x^2 + xy + 1) + y}{x\cos(x^2 + xy + 1) + x + 1}\\\\
y(0) = \sin(1)
\end{cases}
$$

I tried to perform $z = x^2 + xy+1$ and then $z' = \dfrac{y'}{x}$, yet this led me to the writing

$$z'(x\cos(z) + x + 1) = -(x^2+z+1)\left[\cos(z)-1\right]$$

But I don't know how to proceed. Is there some trick for those kind od CP?

Note: $y = y(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both sides by the denominator and we find that
\begin{align}
(2x+y+xy')\cos(x^2+xy+1)=-y-(x+1)y'\,.
\end{align}
Put $u=x^2+xy+1$ and $v=(x+1)y$, the equation above becomes
\begin{align}
u'\cos u=-v'\,.
\end{align}
Integrate both sides to find the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I did not think about a double substitution...

Comment: Just a (probably stupid) question: once I have integrated, I get: $$\sin(u) = -v$$

Now if I come back, I get

$$\sin(x^2 + xy + 1) = -(x+1)y$$

How could I get $y(x)$?

Comment: Not much can be done. Just leave it like that.